# Populate a nil struct inside its method

Tags: go, nullreferenceexception

I don't know if this is possible in Go, but if I call a method on a nil struct, is there a way to populate it?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```golang
type A struct { 
    Name string
}

func (a *A) DoStuff() {
    if a == nil {
        a = &A{Name: "hello"}
    }
}

func main() {
    var a *A
    a.DoStuff()
    println(a.Name) // want "hello"
}
```

but the above does not populate `a` with an instance of `A{}`, which is probably expected.

Is there some trick to accomplish this or is it just not possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a constructor function instead: `func NewA() *A { return &A{ Name: "hello" } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR, you can't. In your method, `a` is a local variable. When you do:

```
a := &A{}
```

You're overwriting the local variable with a new pointer to a new struct. What you want is to overwrite the *existing pointer* to a new struct. The only way to do that is to dereference the pointer:

```
*a := A{}
```

But you can't dereference a `nil` pointer, because it doesn't point to anything; no memory is allocated for it, and your application will crash.